# Appharbor background process not working, no errors shown

Tags: appharbor

I have a background process
that reads messages from the rabbitmq.
It works locally.  But it does not work on appharbor.
I see know errors but the messages are still in the rabbitmq.
Hence its not working.

My console app reads from the rabbitmq and writes to the console.
Requires no users interaction other then ctrl-c to exit.
The documentation for background process is minimal. Not sure of all the rules for a background process.

Is there any logs to determine the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - we recently added [a new logging module](http://blog.appharbor.com/2013/07/01/introducing-realtime-logging) which gives you real-time access to your background worker's STDOUT and STDERR.

You can start a log session by clicking the "Logging" link in the application's nav bar. That should give you more output to help identify and resolve this issue.

Comment: Note use Chrome or FF to view the log session.  IE does not display correctly.